# Is the invoice.paid event the catch-all for Stripe subscriptions

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a very simple use case. I have the typical 3 tier subscription offer and I just need to capture webhook events whenever a user purchases a plan the first time or upgrade/downgrades a plan.

For the first purchase, it is straightforward that I simply watch for `invoice.paid` to know a customer has purchased. However for upgrade/downgrade, on the docs they say to monitor the `customer.subscription.updated` for plan changes but it seems that and this is what I need to confirm, `invoice.paid` is STILL called after an upgrade/downgrade.

If `invoice.paid` is always called regardless of any type of purchase, why don't I just watch for this event and update my database with the user's current plan whenever this event is captured?

Answer (score 0):

The `invoice.paid` event includes details about the invoice but not the subscription. So, for example, if you want to keep track of a customer's current plan and update your database accordingly, only listening to `invoice.paid` won't give you details about the subscription's current state and the changes that were made. You would mean you would still have to make a separate call to retrieve the subscription object and compare this to your database.

Listening to `customer.subscription.updated` means you'll receive a subscription object for any subscription changes and won't have to make a separate request to retrieve the subscription.

Comment: I guess my question then would be in what scenario would it be that the subscription status is not active but `invoice.paid` is sent?

Comment: `status=trialing` is the only one I can think of. Trialing Subscriptions would start the trial period with a free Invoice, so you would get `invoice.paid` then

Comment: Got it, thanks for the additional info. Good thing I don't have trial subscriptions.